# Filling missing dates in python beautiful soup and pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this website from where I scraped data as CSV file. I was able to scrape the date and the price. however the date is in week format and I need to convert it into date format like daily prices for 5 working days. (mon-sat).I used python and pandas and beautiful soup for this. [WHAT I GET AND WHAT I WANT FROM THIS SITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1UhV.png) 
    from urllib.request import urlopen

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError 
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import pandas as pd 
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

try:

```
html = urlopen("https://www.eia.gov/dnav/ng/hist/rngwhhdD.htm")
```

except HTTPError as e:

```
print(e)
```

except URLError:

```
print("Server down or incorrect domain")
```

else:

```
res = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html5lib")



price = res.findAll(class_=["tbody", "td", "B3"])
price_list = []

for tag in price:
    price_tag=tag.getText()
    price_list.append(price_tag)
    print(price_tag)



date = res.findAll(class_=["tbody", "td", "B6"])
date_list = []

for tag in date:
    date_tag=tag.getText()
    date_list.append(date_tag)
    print(date_tag)


d1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_list})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'Price': price_list})
df = pd.concat([d1,d2], axis=1)
print(df)
df.to_csv("Gas Price.csv", index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual Code create a list for each row and an list for each cell, this don't fits together.
Following script search the table (it is the only one that has the attribute summary) and loops over each row (tr). Than it gets from the Week column (td class B6) the first part before the " to " and convert it to an datetime.
For each cell (td class B3) it get the price (or empty string), set the date and increments the date.

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError 
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import pandas as pd 
from urllib.request import urlopen
import datetime

try:
    html = urlopen("https://www.eia.gov/dnav/ng/hist/rngwhhdD.htm")
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
except URLError:
    print("Server down or incorrect domain")
else:
    res = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html5lib")

table = None
for t in res.findAll("table"):
    table = t if "summary" in t.attrs else table
if table == None: exit()

# stop_date = datetime.datetime(year = 2018, month = 7, day = 12)
# today = datetime.datetime.now()
# abort = False

price_list = []
date_list = []

rows = table.findAll("tr")[1:]
for row in rows:
    date = None
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    if cells[0].get("class") == None: continue # placeholder..
    if "B6" in cells[0].get("class"):
        d = cells[0].getText().split(" to ")[0].strip().replace(" ", "")
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d,"%Y%b-%d")
        for cell in cells:
            if "B3" in cell.get("class"): # and abort == False:
                price = cell.getText().strip()
                if price == "" or price == "NA": price = ""
                else: price = float(price)
                price_list.append(price)
                date_list.append(date)
                date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                #if date > today: abort = True
        #if abort == True: break

d1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_list})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'Price': price_list})
df = pd.concat([d1,d2], axis=1)
print(df)
df.to_csv(r"Gas Price.csv", index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't entirely clear what you wanted for Date but I extracted both and called them Start and End Date.

In:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1997 Jan- 6 to Jan-10', '1997 Jan-13 to Jan-17'], 'Price': [3.80, 5.00] })

df['Temp_Year'] = df.Date.str.extract(r'((?:19|20)\d\d)')
df['Temp_Date'] = df.Date.str.replace(r'((?:19|20)\d\d)','')

df[['Start Date', 'End Date']] = df.Temp_Date.str.split('to', expand=True)

df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Temp_Year'] + ' ' + df['Start Date'].str.replace(" ",""))
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Temp_Year'] + ' ' + df['End Date'].str.replace(" ",""))

df.drop(['Temp_Year', 'Temp_Date'], axis=1)
```

Out:

```
|   | Date                  | Price | Start Date | End Date   |
|---|-----------------------|-------|------------|------------|
| 0 | 1997 Jan- 6 to Jan-10 | 3.8   | 1997-01-06 | 1997-01-10 |
| 1 | 1997 Jan-13 to Jan-17 | 5.0   | 1997-01-13 | 1997-01-17 |
```